# Iterating and binding a set to jsp

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I have bind a command with jsp.

When I am iterating it in jsp it doesn't bring value in it and just print out value as it is:

It is printing for example ${project.projectId} as it is and not the value inside it.

Please help.

Comment: Can you define Project entity in code snippet And make it more descriptive.

Comment: @Harjot show your controller class. how you set the `projects` in the request

Comment: Did you add the namespace for c:out?

Comment: @Harjot, what do you see, if you put this `${projects}` before `forEach` ?

Comment: Added Controller class as well. Please go through an suggest.

Comment: Arvind: It shows {projects} printed as such.

Comment: Did you try to replace the line `<td><c:out value="${project.projectId}" /></td>` with simply `<td>${project.projectId}</td>` ?

Comment: Serge: Yes, same results, printed as such. ${project.projectId}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even after adding the namespace, if you get this problem, that means your EL is ignored by the JSP engine. The reason may be an old type web.xml file. Try adding the following to your JSP page (force not to ignore the EL):

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Above problem is fixed with another reference:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26709325/nothing-printed-on-jsp-for-added-model-object?noredirect=1#comment42011174_26709325
```

Real problem lies in old configuration web.xml

Answer (score -1):

You have to include namespace for jstl like

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" 
           uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Comment: I dont think so . he might be missing the `namespace` for jstl . as the expression is not interpreted in jsp

Comment: I have namespace for jstl. Please go through controller class, I added now.

Comment: have you added dependency for it.?

Comment: Yes I have. Can u please let me know how I can bind the project. If you see my jsp, I have given path="clienId" for client but haven't specified any path for projects. Isn't this required?